# JavaScript no funciona en API 17 en adelante

Tags: java, javascript, android

Hice el webview de una app web y este funciona perfectamente con versiones de la API 16 para abajo. Sin embargo, desde la Jelly Bean MRI (API 17) en adelante, hay errores variados (dependiendo de la versión de API) en el JavaScript. Leí que hay que agregar una nueva clase publica de JavascriptInterface() o algo así pra que el webview detecte todos los metodos de javascript y funcione en el webviwew. Pero no se como implementarlo en mi código main_activity.java. Ya tiene el setJavaScriptEnabled("true"), pero eso solo funciona con APIS inferiores a la 17...No se que hacer. Por favor, alguien puede mostrarme como solucionar esto en mi código?

main_activity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/* URL saved to be loaded after fb login */
private static final String target_url="http://www.chapatelo.com.ar/";
private static final String target_url_prefix="www.chapatelo.com.ar";
private Context mContext;
private WebView mWebview;
private WebView mWebviewPop;
private RelativeLayout mContainer;
private long mLastBackPressTime = 0;
private Toast mToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // final View controlsView =
    // findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    //mWebviewPop = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewPop);
    mContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_relative);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.splashLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient());
    mWebview.loadUrl(target_url);

    mContext=this.getApplicationContext();

}


private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
        //Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
        if (host.equals(target_url_prefix))
        {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
            // the page
            if(mWebviewPop!=null){
                mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                mWebviewPop=null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        if(host.equals("m.facebook.com") || host.equals("www.facebook.com")){
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
        // another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                   SslError error) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}

class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                  boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(mWebview.canGoBack()){
        mWebview.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Veo que creas para android mediante webapps, mirate phonegap y con el plugin crosswalk "motor chrome" te aseguras que las webapps vayan bien en casi todas la versiones activas de Android

Answer (score 1):

Hay que dejar en claro que para habilitar Javascript en un WebView se realiza por medio del método **[setJavaScriptEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html?hl=zh-cn#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean))**, esto ha sido siempre desde la API 1 de android.

```
   WebSettings webSettings = myWebview.getSettings();
   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

y veo lo realizas correctamente.

En cuanto a que tienes problemas al funcionar con API 17+ revisa la **[documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)**:

> **Precaución:** Si ha establecido su targetSdkVersion a 17 o más, se debe
>   añadir la anotación **@JavascriptInterface** a cualquier método que desea
>   estén disponibles para JavaScript (el método también debe ser
>   público). **Si usted no proporciona la anotación, el método no es
>   accesible en su página web cuando se ejecuta en Android 4.2 o
>   superior.**

Agrega la anotación `@JavascriptInterface` a tus métodos donde uses javascript:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void miMetodoJS() {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que no utilizo JS en el código Android. Lo que le sucede a un amigo que tiene un Android 4.2 es que carga la app, desaparece el Splash despues de unos segundos, aparece la pantalla principal, y el cliquea sobre un botón que hace un llamado a una función JS para ingresar. Esto no ocurre. Se le queda la pantalla igual que como estaba antes. Tal y como si JS no respondiese a su click. Vaya coincidencia que leí que en la api 17 en adelante hay que setear otra configuracion de JS para que el Android detecte bien el código de la página que se carga en la webview.

Comment: En resumen, solamente la página web tiene javascript. Dentro de la app android no lo uso nunca. Por eso no entiendo bien eso de colocar la anotacion de addjavascriptinterface cada vez que utilice un "metodo" JS. Debido a que no uso ninguno. Todo el JS es externo a la app. La webview solo la carga. Como podría hacer para que funcione en api17+?

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en la app en sí. Problemas en el css y el display de ciertos elementos para determinado tipo de pantallas. No era problema en el android. Este funciona perfectamente bien.